# Docker run, one line script based on env variables in docker run

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a one line shell script while running a container...

something like this:

docker run ubuntu:updated sh -c "colors=(red orange white gray);LINE=$((ARRAY_INDEX + 1));echo ${colors[${LINE}]}"

ARRAY_INDEX is a environment variable available inside my container image..is it possible?

Comment: Changing the double quotes to single quotes `sh -c 'container command with $CONTAINER_VARIABLES'` should make a difference; but it seems like it'd be easier to write that as an actual script and `COPY` it into your image in your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is my attempt below:

**NOTE**: I passed an env variable `ARRAY_INDEX` to be able to reference it inside the container, if your variable is embedded into the image, you obviously don't need to do that.

> $ docker run -it --rm -e ARRAY_INDEX=1 ubuntu bash -c 'colors=(red orange white gray);LINE=$((ARRAY_INDEX + 1));echo ${colors[${LINE}]}'
>
> white